# how to pass parameters from main activity to @Get API

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
public interface CurrentWeatherApi {
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather?q=California&APPID=e8b8a84d0dcbec867ba66a34d376562f")
    Call<CurrentWeather> getCurrentWeather();
}
```

Here is my Interface, I want to pass City Name from Main activity for a dynamic get API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the following changes and call from the activity passing those params

```
   public interface CurrentWeatherApi {

    @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    Call<CurrentWeather> getCurrentWeather(@Query("q") String cityName,@Query("APPID") String appID);

}
```

so the call will look like below

```
Call<CurrentWeather> repos = service.getCurrentWeather("California","e8b8a84d0dcbec867ba66a34d376562f");
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
@GET("/data/2.5/weather?q=:CityName&APPID=e8b8a84d0dcbec867ba66a34d376562f")
Call<CurrentWeather> getCurrentWeather(String CityName);
```

and call it like

```
retrofit.getCurrentWeather("California")
```